# Can I say "It's a heat"?

Tags: articles

I wonder can I say

> "It's a heat"

meaning

> "It's a very hot weather"

or

> "it's a very high temperature"

I know there should be an article, but I didn't encounter example with the indefinite article before the word "heat".

Comment: Almost everyone would just say *it's hot*. If I heard *it's a heat*, I would interpret it as meaning *it's a* ***race***.

Comment: You can say it is "a heat wave" to denote that it is a specific period of unusually hot weather.

Comment: You might say "It's a **hot** heat" or "It's hot" but I don't think you'd say "It's a heat" unless it was a tie in a race :)